# AngularFireList push error: Argument of type '{ message: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ChatMessage[]'

Tags: angular, angular5, angularfire

Here is my ChatMessage model:

```
 export class ChatMessage{
            $key?: string;
            email?:string;
            userName?:string;
            message?:string;
            timeSent?: Date = new Date();
        }
```

and this is my code for AngularFireList:

```
chatMessages: AngularFireList<ChatMessage[]>;

const timestamp = this.getTimeStamp();
    //const email = this.user.email;
    const email = "example@abc.com";


this.chatMessages.push({
  message: msg,
  timeSent: timestamp,
  email: email,
  //userName: this.userName,
  userName: "user-test",


});

 getTimeStamp(){
    const now = new Date();
    const date = now.getUTCFullYear() + '/' +
                 (now.getUTCMonth() + 1) + '/' +
                 now.getUTCDate();
    const time =  now.getUTCHours() +':'+
                  now.getUTCMinutes() + ':'+
                  now.getUTCSeconds();    

    return (date + ' '+ time);              
  }
```

I have an error saying:

> message: 'Argument of type '{ message: string; timeSent: string; email: string; userName: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ChatMessage[]'.
>     Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'message' does not exist in type 'ChatMessage[]'.

Answer (score 1):

```
this.chatMessages.push(
  [
    {
      message: '',
      timeSent: timestamp,
      email: '',
      // userName: this.userName,
      userName: 'user-test',
    }
  ]
);
```

or

`chatMessages: AngularFireList<ChatMessage[]>;`

replace to

`chatMessages: AngularFireList<ChatMessage>;`

Comment: AngularFireList ??

Comment: import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList } from "angularfire2/database";

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your `getTimeStamp()` function, which returns a `string`, not a `Date`.

Hence, when you do

```
this.chatMessages.push({
  message: msg,
  timeSent: timestamp,
  email: email,
  userName: "user-test",
});
```

the object you are trying to push doesn't satisfy the interface. You can either modify the interface to have `timeSent` of type string, or modify your `getTimeStamp` function to return a `Date`

Answer (score 0):

The correction: Please note that `AngularFireList` requires type of a **single element** of the array.

Do not put `[]` brackets after `ChatMessage` in `AngularFireList`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I tried this instead(works perfectly):

```
getTimeStamp(): Date{
const now = new Date();
const date = now.getUTCFullYear() + '/' +
  (now.getUTCMonth() + 1) + '/' +
  now.getUTCDate();

const time = now.getUTCHours() + ':' +
  now.getUTCMinutes() + ':' +
  now.getUTCSeconds();
return now;
```

hope this is valueable for you or anyone else. btw it's in Angular verstion 10.X ;)